# Automatically Adding Header in IOS Mobile App?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am new to IOS Mobile App/XCode 4.6.2, I created sample App in that automatically adding header in top.

Can you tell me how can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please make your question clear and specific.

Comment: do you mean in table view ? can be more specific and add example app etc.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar - Just double click on naviagtion bar

Comment: @bhavyakothari,I simple add a button on my app and run that application. in my simulator it is shown header

Comment: @BishalGhimire, I simple add a button on my app and run that application. in my simulator it is shown header.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "Header". Also which version of iOS? Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: as of Feb2014 you must use XCode5 else your app will not get approved. Even your edited question is not clear ! try to share some images links.

Comment: @ManojKumar please follow `BishalGhimire` and `ShreyanshShah's` answer. It will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are using **pushViewController** through **navigationController** herder will be added. 
That header is called Navigation bar in iOS.

To hide that please write below line in **viewDidload** or **viewWillAppear**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

or

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

I hope, this will help you. :)

Comment: @Shryansh Shah, I simple add a button on my app and run that application. in my simulator it is shown header.

Comment: @Zaph, actually Image is not uploading in my computer, can you tell me  your mail id I will send you attachemtn.

Comment: Just describe the "Header", is there text, if so what is it. An image, if so describe it. The word "Header" is to general.

Comment: @ManojKumar :- Can u plz add some code so.. we can understand what you want to say..